# tf.where operation fails to work with model optimizer openvino

Tags: tensorflow, keras, openvino

I am getting shape inference error when I try to run openvino model optimizer on a simple custom layer model. Here is unit test:

```
import os
import shutil
import pytest

import subprocess
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Layer


class CustomLayer(Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):
        arr_0 = inputs[0][:, 0, 0]
        arr_1 = inputs[1][:, 0, 1]

        diff = tf.abs(tf.subtract(arr_0, arr_1))
        large_diff = tf.where(diff > 1., 1., 0.)

        # return diff # this return statement works with model optimizer
        return large_diff # this return statement fails with model optimizer


@pytest.fixture
def model():
    input_1 = Input(shape=(10, 2), dtype=tf.float32)
    input_2 = Input(shape=(10, 2), dtype=tf.float32)

    output = CustomLayer()([input_1, input_2])
    model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=output)

    return model


def test_init(model: Model):
    input_1 = np.array(range(20, 40)).reshape(1, 10, 2)
    input_2 = np.array(range(40, 60)).reshape(1, 10, 2)

    output = model([input_1, input_2])

    assert np.allclose(output, 1.)


def test_save_convert_model(model: Model):
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    dir_path = os.path.join(dir_path, 'resources/infershape')

    shutil.rmtree(dir_path, ignore_errors=True)
    model.save(dir_path)

    inp = "input_3,input_4"
    ins = "[1,10,2],[1,10,2]"
    mo = "/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/mo_tf.py"
    cmd = "python {}".format(mo)
    cmd = "{} "\
          "--saved_model_dir {} "\
          "--output_dir {} "\
          "--input {} "\
          "--input_shape {} ".format(cmd, dir_path, dir_path, inp, ins)
    print(cmd)
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=True)
```

Here is the error message that is produced.

```
tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:1137] Optimization results for grappler item: graph_to_optimize
  function_optimizer: Graph size after: 22 nodes (18), 21 edges (18), time = 1.352ms.
  function_optimizer: function_optimizer did nothing. time = 0.03ms.

[ ERROR ]  Cannot infer shapes or values for node "PartitionedCall/model_1/custom_layer_1/SelectV2".
[ ERROR ]  Input 0 of node PartitionedCall/model_1/custom_layer_1/SelectV2 was passed float from PartitionedCall/model_1/custom_layer_1/Greater_port_0_ie_placeholder:0 incompatible with expected bool.
[ ERROR ]  
[ ERROR ]  It can happen due to bug in custom shape infer function <function tf_native_tf_node_infer at 0x7f2efcac24c0>.
[ ERROR ]  Or because the node inputs have incorrect values/shapes.
[ ERROR ]  Or because input shapes are incorrect (embedded to the model or passed via --input_shape).
[ ERROR ]  Run Model Optimizer with --log_level=DEBUG for more information.
[ ERROR ]  Exception occurred during running replacer "REPLACEMENT_ID" (<class 'extensions.middle.PartialInfer.PartialInfer'>): Stopped shape/value propagation at "PartitionedCall/model_1/custom_layer_1/SelectV2" node.
```

Please tell me what to either change in my code or if openvino issue, please tell me so I can handle differently. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Model Optimizer cannot infer shapes or values for the specified node. It can happen because the node inputs have incorrect values/shapes, or because the input shapes are incorrect. You can specify the input shapes by referring to the following link:
https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_convert_model_Converting_Model_General.html#when_to_specify_input_shapes

Comment: If you please seen the unit test, you can see the input shape is specified, yet this error persists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your model's topology is supported by OpenVINO.
Please check your model topology at [Supported Topologies](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_convert_model_Convert_Model_From_TensorFlow.html#supported_topologies). If it not listed there, then the model is not supported and failure in conversion is expected.

Please also check the supported operations in [TensorFlow* Supported Operations](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_Supported_Frameworks_Layers.html#tensorflow_supported_operations) and [TensorFlow 2 Keras* Supported Operations](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_Supported_Frameworks_Layers.html#tensorflow_2_keras_supported_operations).